# Alternate to oracle first_value() in sqlserver 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, window-functions

I have a below query in oracle:

```
 SELECT DISTINCT
       first_value(status_date) OVER(PARTITION BY ccp_seq_no ORDER BY status_date DESC) status_date,
       first_value(payment_status) OVER(PARTITION BY ccp_seq_no ORDER BY status_date DESC) payment_status
FROM dc_ccp_detail d;
```

How would i write it in sqlserver 2005

Comment: How would i write it in sqlserver 2005

Comment: That's a strange query anyway getting all latest dates with their status. You'll get, say, 2017-05-20 | 'okay' ; 2017-06-25 | 'okay'  ; 2017-06-25 | 'fail' and know that one or more CCPs' latest dates were May 20 and June 25, and that some were okay and one or more failed. This seems very blurry information. (And in Oracle you'd rather aggregate with `GROUP BY` and `KEEP LAST` for such task, than appying `FIRST_VALUE` to all records.)

Comment: Sorry that was incomplete query,

Comment: There is a where clause

Comment: Where ccp_seq_no =5

Comment: Is there still need of join?

Comment: `ccp_seq_no =5`? Why then `PARTITION BY ccp_seq_no`? And why not simply `MAX(status_date)`? Why `DISTINCT`? That `WHERE` clause makes the query even worse.

Comment: So the question had better be "how would I write it in Oracle" :-)

Answer (score 1):

In your comments you alter the query to

```
SELECT DISTINCT
 first_value(status_date) OVER(PARTITION BY ccp_seq_no ORDER BY status_date DESC) status_date,
 first_value(payment_status) OVER(PARTITION BY ccp_seq_no ORDER BY status_date DESC) payment_status
FROM dc_ccp_detail d
WHERE ccp_seq_no = 5;
```

which is a horribly obfuscated

```
SELECT status_date, payment_status
FROM dc_ccp_detail
WHERE ccp_seq_no = 5
ORDER BY status_date DESC
FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY;
```

in Oracle 12c and standard SQL and

```
SELECT TOP(1) status_date, payment_status
FROM dc_ccp_detail
WHERE ccp_seq_no = 5
ORDER BY status_date DESC;
```

in SQL Server.